# Why don't I have a Documentation link in the django 1.0 admin page?

Tags: django, django-admin

On my django 0.96 admin page, there was a "Documentation" link which led to all kinds of nice introspection features. After installing django 1.02, I no longer have this link. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is revealed here:
http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/b4670a85dfa6322/7b72917ce7ef99e?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=django+admin+interface+documentation+link&pli=1

Answer (score 3):

You have to change a few things in your urls.py and settings.py:

from urls.py:

```
# Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
# to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
# (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: That gives an error when I include it. There is additional discussion about which lines should be uncommented for which django version in the comments of http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/. I see the admin page fine. Just not the documentation link.

Comment: Don't use "admin.site.urls" unless you've upgraded to a fairly recent trunk version of Django (NOT 1.0.2).  You do, however, want the admin/doc/ line in your URLconf and django.contrib.admindocs in INSTALLED_APPS.  Neither of those was necessary in 0.96.